# When are interrogative pronouns (or relative pronouns) needed in this context?

Tags: questions, relative-pronouns

Look at the dictionary meanings below. I have copied them from the New Oxford American English Dictionary (the *application* for the dictionary on my Macintosh laptop):

**pedant**: (noun) a person *who is* excessively concerned with minor details and rules or with displaying academic learning.

**virtuoso**:(noun) a person highly skilled in music or another artistic pursuit.

I'd have expected *who is* to be present in the case of virtuoso as well. Is the use of *who is* optional in this context?

Comment: Dictionary definitions are rarely full sentences, and use ellipsis to save space. If a reader can easily understand the definition of *virtuoso* without the words "who is", what's the point of adding them - to please the *pedant?* ;-)

Comment: It's fine. The AdjP "highly skilled in music ..." serves as a post-head modifier of "person".

Comment: Note that when adjectives have their own post-head dependents, they normally occur in post-head position. The adjective "skilled" has the adverb  "highly" and the PP "in music ..." as dependents, so it cannot occur in attributive position, cf. the ungrammatical *"a highly skilled in music or another artistic pursuit person".

Comment: I am confused. Are sentences like "The word 'virtuoso' means a person highly skilled in music." grammatical? I tried to illustrate my question with the help of sentences from a dictionary. I have always wondered if constructs such as "that is", "who is" are _required_ when describing objects. Can someone answer more definitively?